# Why Docker compose link does not work in react app?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I've two application as a docker container. ReactJS as frontend and springboot application as backend.

When I up both of applications on windows docker desktop toolbox, I cant login from frontend because of backend api not accessible. All my containers use default network.

in react app I use this link for access to backend  `API_URL: 'http://backend:8080/api/'`

docker-compose.yml is here.

```
backend:
container_name: backend
image: backend:2.0.1b4
command: sh -c "/wait && catalina.sh run"
ports:
  - 8080:8080
environment:
  - ROTATOR_CLIENT=agent_url:9091
  - MAST_CLIENT=agent_url:9092
  - working-environment=RLAS
  - DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres_url:5432/postgres?schema=public
  - DB_USER=postgres
  - DB_PASSWORD=postgres
  - WAIT_HOSTS=postgres_url:5432
  - WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL=5
external_links:
  - database:postgres_url
  - agent:agent_url
restart: always


frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: frontend:2.0.1b4
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - base_url=backend_url:9090
    external_links:
      - backend:backend_url
    restart: always
```

error is that:
[image]

Comment: Try putting `depends_on: backend` in your frontend container config in docker-compose. Do containers work independently (connected to localhost backend/frontend respectively)?

Comment: @k-wasilewski thank your suggest, but I tried it. Not worked. By the way I found the solution. I've changed my base url backedn:8080 to localhost:8080. this is absurd but works now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you figured out, you'll have to use `http://localhost:8080` instead of `http://backend:8080` as the URL.

This is because client-side fetching data with JavaScript occurs in *your* browser, and not inside the container. This therefore happens outside of the docker network.

Comment: This explanation is highly logical. thanks