# Communication between UI layer and Rest service not happening properly over dockercompose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

**The communication between the front end layer(React) and the backend layer (Spring boot: Rest API) is not happening properly over docker compose**

```
version: "3"

services:
 backend-service:
    build:./backend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
   

    ui-service:
        build: ./ui
        ports:
          - 8085:8085
```

**So when I am calling https://localhost:8080 from the front end layer it works fine. Whereas when I call https://backend-service:8080 from the front end layer it gives me net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

That is bit unusual. Wondering if I did something wrong or this as designed ?

Comment: In another comment you mention [Why Docker compose link does not work in react app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851376/why-docker-compose-link-does-not-work-in-react-app) and [an answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62852027/10008173) points out: "client-side fetching data with JavaScript occurs in your browser, and not inside the container. This therefore happens outside of the docker network."

Answer (score -1):

From [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

You can try including the `container_name` field. More about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#container_name)

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
 backend-service:
    build:./backend
    container_name: backend-service
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
   

    ui-service:        
        build: ./ui
        ports:
          - 8085:8085
```

If you do not specify `container_name` your container will be likely to be named `backend-service-1` or similar. You can check container`s name using` docker ps` or looking at compose logs.

Comment: My question is why localhost is working here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851376/why-docker-compose-link-does-not-work-in-react-app

Comment: Nvm found a link. Although I am still not 100% sure why it works

Comment: The React application is making requests from a browser, not a container, so it can't see these host names.  Even if the `ui` service was making direct requests to `backend` (maybe through a Webpack proxy configuration) `container_name:` isn't necessary here.